# Error 403: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for a terraformproject

Tags: google-compute-engine, terraform

J added all the roles.I still cannot get terraform to build the project.

> googlecompute: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.zones.get' permission for 'pr
>   ojects/terraform-3/zones/us-central1', forbidden Build 'googlecompute'
>   errored: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 403: Required
>   'compute.zones.get' permis sion for
>   'projects/terraform-3/zones/us-central1', forbidden

Comment: The error is telling you that you don't have the required permissions to read the compute zones. This is a pretty minimal permission so it suggests that the credentials you are using don't have any permissions at all. You should fix that and retry. Also it helps to post a [mcve] when asking a question. This should include the minimal code needed to reproduce the error and in your case should also show the permissions you have for the credentials you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of issue might arise if somehow your cloudservices robot gets removed as a project editor. My best guess is that in your case this is the issue.

This might happen due to API call which has SetIamPolicy that is missing cloudservices robot from the "roles/editor" bindings. SetIamPolicy is a straight PUT, it will override with whatever policy is provided in the request. You can get the list of IAM policies for your project with below command as [given in this article.](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/get-iam-policy)

**gcloud projects get-iam-policy [project-id]**

From the list, you can check whether below service account has the editor permission or not.

To fix the issue, you can [grant the mentioned service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting_access_to_team_members) **"Editor"** permission and check whether that solves the issue or not.

[id]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com