# Permission compute.regions.get error in terraform google kubernetes engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to use `terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google//modules/beta-private-cluster` module of version "~> 7.3" to create a cluster in region `europe-west2`. But I keep getting error:

```
Error: googleapi: Error 403: Google Compute Engine: Required 'compute.regions.get' 
permission for 'projects/***/regions/europe-west2'., forbidden
```

The weird thing is that I'm trying to do that using user with `Editor` role. So, it should have permission to read region. I tried to add more roles for the user (made it all kind of admins), but the result is still the same.
Could you please advice, where can be my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve that problem. It appeared that my provisioner dropped some roles, which are required for GKE to work properly. In particular,

- `serviceAccount:service-${project-number}@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com` must be `roles/compute.serviceAgent`.
- `serviceAccount:service-${project-number}@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com` must be `roles/compute.serviceAgent`.

To find that I disabled Kubernetes engine service and enabled it back and google cloud automatically recovered required roles for that service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your `[id]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` service account has the editor role.

List all service accounts with `gcloud projects get-iam-policy [project-id]` command and look for the account. it should look similar to this:

```
- members:
  - serviceAccount:67993345594-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:679934532594@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:service-674567382594@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:test2-468@asdf.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:asdf@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/editor
```

Second from the top is the account you're looking for and the bottom line says "roles/editor" which is the correct situation.

If this account doesn't have this role you can grant it using command:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [project] / 
--member serviceAccount:[id]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/editor
```

It's all described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource).

Very similar issues were discussed on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48236384/12257250) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58565352/12257250).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it appeared that there are more service accounts involved in GKE processing. And I accidentally removed their roles. I posted my discovery, which helped me. To find that I disabled Kubernetes engine service and enabled it back and google cloud automatically recovered required roles for that service accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after switching account in `gcloud`.

I solve it by running

```bash
gcloud auth application-default login
```

It sets application default credentials for Packer/Terraform to call Google APIs.

source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default